# Looping through a list read by pickle to find userid

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7, pickle

I am having trouble looping through a list read by pickle. The Ultimate aim of this code was to loop through each Item and return the id number of each item.

```
## Opening the file, and loading it into a list##
with open('TEMP_ITEMS.txt', 'rb') as openfile:
    items = pickle.load(openfile)
```

My attempt at trying to loop through this and find the id numbers was based on some old xml scraping techniques, but for some reason the logic doesn't apply here.

```
for item in enumerate(items):

    pattern0 = re.compile('ID: (.*?) <br>')
    idnumber = float(re.findall(pattern0, items[0])[0])
    print "ID Number: ",idnumber
```

Example of the contents of TEMP_ITEMS.txt

```
(lp0
S'\n                <item>\n                    <title>Timmy</title>\n                    <link>caturl</link>\n                    <description><![CDATA[\n                                Timmy <br>\n                                ID: 3712 <br>\n                                Age: 10 <br>\n                                Weight: 7lbs <br>\n                                Time: 17:23 <br>\n                                Cat Name: Timmy <br>\n\n                    ]]></description>\n                    <guid isPermaLink="false">04e72b29-065d-4893-a4d2-f16ff30a283e</guid>\n                    <pubDate>Fri, 21 Jun 2013 01:09:05 GMT</pubDate>\n                </item>'
p1
aS'\n                <item>\n                    <title>George</title>\n                    <link>caturl</link>\n                    <description><![CDATA[\n                                George <br>\n                                ID: 4124 <br>\n                                Age: 14 <br>\n                                Weight: 8lbs <br>\n                                Time: 15:41 <br>\n                                Cat Name: George <br>\n\n                    ]]></description>\n                    <guid isPermaLink="false">212f9fbf-564b-470a-a64a-ef51036ff06a</guid>\n                    <pubDate>Fri, 21 Jun 2013 01:28:20 GMT</pubDate>\n                </item>'
p2
a.
```

Any help or advice on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Kind regards AEA

## Code used under recommendations of falsetru, which returns an error

```
import pickle
import re

with open('TEMP_RSS_ITEMS.txt', 'rb') as temp_rss_items_open4:
    items = pickle.load(temp_rss_items_open4)        
    print items
    for item in enumerate(items):
        pattern0 = re.compile('ID: (.*) <br>')
        for idnumber in re.findall(pattern0, item):
            print idnumber
```

Error this code it producing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Sharing/test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    for idnumber in re.findall(pattern0, item):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
>>>
```

Comment: `pattern0 = re.compile(...); re.findall(pattern0)` no business of `item`?

Comment: Hello @iMom0 I am still learning to code, if something seems blazingly obviously wrong then it probably is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a non-greedy version of `.*`:

```
pattern0 = re.complie(r'ID: (.*?) <br>')
```

or '+` if ID has only digits:

```
pattern0 = re.complie(r'ID: (\d+)')
```

**UPDATE**

```
import pickle
import re

pattern0 = re.compile('ID: (.*) <br>')
with open('TEMP_RSS_ITEMS.txt', 'rb') as f:
    items = pickle.load(f)        
    for item in items:
        for idnumber in pattern0.findall(item):
            print idnumber
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @falsetru, I have managed to fix the first problem with this code by changing to `for item in enumerate(items):` the issue now is that the looping script only ever returns the first item in the list, where as I want it to return the id for the first item on the first loop, then the id for the second item in the list and so on..  Any ideas ?

Comment: Hey thanks @falsetru, unfortunately it still returns an error, I have input the code used and the error returned at the end of the question. Any further ideas? :S

Comment: Brilliant! Working code, thanks a bunch, do you mind explaining why this works and why previous attempts or my attempt did not?

Comment: `re.findall(pattern0, item)` was my fault. It should be `pattern0.findall(item)`.

Comment: `float` is not needed unless you do some arithmetic with `id`.

Comment: `re.findall(....)[0]` return only the first match. It will not be the issue if there is only one match.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing items [0] with item:

```
for item in enumerate(items):
    pattern0 = re.compile('ID: (.*?) <br>')
    idnumber = float(re.findall(pattern0, item)[0])
```

If you are iterating over each item, then why not use each item?

Comment: Cheers for answer yeh I did try this it returned this error: `TypeError: expected string or buffer`